# Matching a variable with a checkbox label

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Hours spent trying to get the correct syntax for this.  I want to find the checkbox that has a label matching the variable `'mytext'`, and then make that checkbox label red. I seem to have tried all combinations of `find()` and `text()` but nothing works. Please help. https://jsfiddle.net/n4f50j3m/

```
<div id="Both_containers">
<div id="Upper_container">
<label><input type="checkbox" value="PP1" />Iron ore</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="PP2" />Coal</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="PP3" />Flux</label>
</div>
</div>
```

.

```
var mytext = "Coal";
$('#Both_containers div label').find(mytext).text().addClass('make_red');
```

.

```
.make_red{
 color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friend here is `:contains()`.

try with

```
$('#Both_containers div label:contains(' + mytext + ')').addClass('make_red');
```

**Demo**

```js
var mytext = "Coal";
$('#Both_containers div label:contains(' + mytext + ')').addClass('make_red');
```

```css
.make_red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Both_containers">
  <div id="Upper_container">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="PP1" />Iron ore</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="PP2" />Coal</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="PP3" />Flux</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And you are my friend too.  Your help very much appreciated.  Will accept as answer in 10 mins.

Comment: @Silverburch no problem, happy to help